# How to get audio from BT headset mic?

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I have BT headset with mic.

It is connected to the Linux device as HSP (Pulseaudio 9.0 native) via Bluez5.

I want to get sound from mic.

How to do this?

When I do `parec -r --device="...."` there is nothing. Looks like I need to send "RING" command to the headset somehow. But I don't know how.

p.s. I have no GUI. Only console.

p.p.s The Linux device has no sound card (if it matters)

Comment: Do you see volume level changes in `pavucontrol` when you speak into it? Can you record from it with `parecord -d your-device-name` etc.? (Use `pacmd list-sources | grep name:` to get the name, or look it up in `pavucontrol`).

Comment: Sorry, did not mentioned that I have no GUI. Only console.
`~# pacmd list-sources | grep name
        name: <bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_12_C4_E3.monitor>
                device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        name: <bluez_source.FC_58_FA_12_C4_E3>
                device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
`

Comment: So does `parecord -d bluez_source.FC_58_FA_12_C4_E3 test.wav` work? Do you "get sound" this way?

Comment: Sorry, in original topic was wrong command. It should be parec.

So yes, I tried to record. But the output is empty. It has only the wave header.

Answer (score 1):

From all of the sudden I have one of these Bluetooth adapters with Broadcom hardware and firmware. It does not support HSP from the box. [You need to add firmware patch](http://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/).